# Determining the order of succession for a 3-phase current

Tags: three-phase

On some exams the following question appeared that I am not capable of answering:

How to determine the order of succession of the 3 phases of a 3-phase power using as a load either:
a) 2 lamps and 1 coil or
b) 2 lamps and 1 capacitor.

I guess it has to do with the different kind of load a lamp and a coil or capacitor are but I am not sure how to use them to achieve the desired output.

Can someone think of a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: The current phase shift will tell which is the coil phase lag and cap phase lead by monitoring current and voltage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two lamps and a capacitor (or inductor) can do the job: -

[image]

Inductor version: -

[image]

The maths is quite easy to follow; it's all about the phase shift produced by the capacitor (or inductor) and how it changes the voltage seen across each lamp.

Images (and explanation) from [this site](https://www.elprocus.com/ac-mains-phase-sequence-indicator/).

Comment: Huh. Never seen this before. Very interesting.